# Tomcat Presenting SSL Credentials

Tags: apache, mongodb, tomcat, ssl

I have set up my MongoDB to only accept connections over SSL. Mongo has a handle to a certificate that I generated with the following commands

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out server-cert.crt -keyout server-private.key
cat server-cert.crt server-private.key > /etc/ssl/mongoSSL.pem
```

I added the following to my /etc/mongod.cnf...

```
sslMode=requireSSL
sslPEMKeyFile=/etc/ssl/mongo/mongoSSL.pem
```

Whenever Tomcat attempts to talk to Mongo, it fails due to not presenting the SSL certificate.
I set up my /opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml to have the following

```
<Connector port="27017" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="/etc/ssl/mongo/mongoSSL.pem"/>
```

This, however does not work. Does anyone have a link to a tutorial that can further my knowledge on how this is done? I found a tutorial to configure SSL with [Apache](http://crunchify.com/step-by-step-guide-to-enable-https-or-ssl-correct-way-on-apache-tomcat-server-port-8443/) and I found the [Apache Docs on SSL Support](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support) however neither seem to be for my use case.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whenever Tomcat attempts to talk to Mongo, it fails due to not presenting the SSL certificate. I set up my /opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml to have the following

Your assumption is wrong,your server.xml configuration doesn't instruct Tomcat to present SSL certificate to MongoDB. It tells Tomcat to listen to secure (https) connection on port 27017 (which is occupied by MongoDB anyway). You should discard that Tomcat connector setting.

In fact `sslMode=requireSSL` doesn't instruct MongoDB to require a client certificate for a two ways authentication. It only instruct MongoDB to accept only secured SSL connections.

What you need to do is not to configure Tomcat, but the MongoDB driver (I assume Java here since you are using Tomcat).

Configuring the Java driver is fairly easy. [You can find the instructions here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/reference/connecting/ssl/)